# Executar comando SQL no terminal

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou querendo executar comando sql através do prompt do Windows mas não sei quais as configurações iniciais pra se fazer isso.Alguém pode me dizer?

Detalhe:Tem de ser no terminal do windows.

Comment: Que configurações? Pedidos de softwares/tutorias estão fora do escopo do site. Recomendo a leitura da [tour] e [ask]. Tentou registrar o executável do postgres (via linha de comando) no PATH (variável de ambiente) do windows ?

Comment: Sugiro alterar o título: Como executar comando SQL no terminal?

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza a ferramenta [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html), presente na instalação do PostgreSQL.

Para logar, digite:

```
psql -U usuarioDoBanco nomeDeUmBanco
```

Depois, pode executar comandos, como:

```
select datname, oid from pg_database;
```

Imagem de comando para conexão no terminal:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tem de ser no terminal !!

Comment: Sim, o psql é no terminal!

Comment: Muito obrigado ,entendi

Answer (score 0):

segue um exemplo sem precisar se logar

```
psql --command="select codigo from produto where codigo = 'codigo_do_produto'" --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=postgres --dbname=banco
```

Comment: Esta resposta foi sinalizada como de baixa qualidade devido ao tamanho ou conteúdo. Por favor, se possível e se esta for uma solução ao problema, explique melhor como você o resolveu. O código pode ser trivial para você, mas para outros usuários pode não ser.